# Shuffle words on hover only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a sort of a animated header for my homepage where I want the words to hover and change their horizontal location randomly.

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <a href="#">
    <span>One</span> <span>100</span> <span>Twenty</span> <span>2000</span>
  </a>
</header>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($){

 $.fn.shuffle = function() {

    var allElems = this.get(),
        getRandom = function(max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        },
        shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
            var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
            allElems.splice(random, 1);
            return randEl;
       });

    this.each(function(i){
        $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
    });

    return $(shuffled);

};

})(jQuery);


$("header").mouseenter(function(){

     $('span').shuffle();

});
```

I got this random shuffle code from css-tricks.com ands its a bit quirky. When I hover on the header it goes a little too crazy with the shuffleing and when i want to click on the link it somehow triggers the function again:

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/5CMCH/1/

What I want to achieve is to have only one change when I mouseenter it, click on the link to get to the index, and another one when  I mouseenter again etc.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I hover on the header it goes a little too crazy

That's because the event gets fired for the `span` elements as well.

Check if the `event.currentTarget` is your `header` element, and only shuffle the spans then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function, it fires an event only once and then removes the handler:

```
$("header").one('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    $('span').shuffle();
});
```

Updated version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CMCH/3/).

Comment: that's it, but also add a `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the crazyness. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/5CMCH/4/)

Comment: OK. this makes sense, but it only triggers it once, if id like to shuffle it again, i'd have to refresh the page. I'd like to do it like: in, out, in out … and everytime it changes. I tried Klasman's answer, it kindof worked, but the inline-block makes a mess out of the page, when I hover on the header in and out.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript seems to be fine;
Looks like the event is getting triggered a lot of times because the region of the `a`-tag changes during the shuffle. You can try to add some styling to the `a`-tag, like padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/5CMCH/2/