# Shuffle words in a list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made the following fiddle where the words from one list can be dragged and dropped to the other and vice versa.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/E4qzS/4/)

The code for drag and drop is fairly straightforward.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

and each word has `draggable="true"`

while both divs have `ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"`

Now, I need a function to shuffle the words in each list.

Basically, on clicking a button, it should call a function that will shuffle the words present in either list. Honestly, i have NO idea on how to do that. I was thinking of using Javascript's

`var input = a.getElementsByTagName('span')` where, in my Fiddle, the `<span>` contains each separate word.

At the same time, I'm wondering if it is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813860/shuffle-words-on-hover-only-once). If it is, can someone help me on how to use it for my current problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely [Google hadn't any hits](http://google.com/search?q=shuffle+array+javascript) for "shuffle array javascript"?

Comment: If you read my question, I've clearly tagged a similar question. Please read before commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following `shuffle` function:  [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

```
function shuffle(o){ 
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
```

Example using `jQuery`:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/E4qzS/11/

```
$('#shuffle').click(function(){
    var spanArray = [];
    $('[id^=div]').each(function(){
        spanArray.length = 0;
        $(this).find('span').each(function(){
            spanArray.push($(this));    
        });
        spanArray = shuffle(spanArray);
        $(this).empty();
        for(var i = 0;i<spanArray.length;i++)
            $(this).append(spanArray[i]);    
     });  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the awesome [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) or [lodash](http://lodash.com). These libraries provide utility functions for javascript, which provide a lot of good functions.

Now to shuffle, do this:

```
// your array
myWordArray = [...]
$('.shuffle').click(function {
  myWordArray = _.shuffle(myWordArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use simple JavaScript you could do something like this:

Add a shuffle button to the HTML:

```
<button id='btn-shuffle'>SHUFFLE</button>
```

Add these functions to the JS:

```
function shuffleNodes(parent) {
    var nodes = parent.childNodes;
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        arr.push(nodes[i]);
    }
    arr.sort(function() {
        return Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    });
    parent.innerHTML = '';
    for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        parent.appendChild(arr[j]);
    }
}

document.getElementById('btn-shuffle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    shuffleNodes(document.getElementById('div1'));
    shuffleNodes(document.getElementById('div2'));
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imcg/9EDzN/